# How to restore .bak file using pg_restore command through cmd in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, pg-restore

I have a test.bak file created with pg_dump command which has a hypertable and i have created a new database Performance_Test in postgreSQL.

The database was dumped using the command:

`pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 -Fc -f "D:\Database Backup\temp.bak" Performace_Test`

I want to restore that test.bak file in Performance_Test.

How can i do that?

Comment: It depends on how the `test.bak` was created. So what was the command you used to make it?

Comment: I have created test.bak file with the command : pg_dump  -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432  -Fc -f "D:\Database Backup\temp.bak" Performace_Test.

Comment: @Akanksha : you should add that detail to the question, instead of a comment.

Comment: Timescale has instructions how to restore a backup: https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/backup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore doing the below(with caveats noted further on):

```
pg_restore -h localhost -d Performace_Test -U postgres -p 5432 "D:\Database Backup\temp.bak"
```

The caveats are:

1. If Performace_Test was created as mixed case by quoting you will need to quote the name above e.g. "Performace_Test"
2. If Performace_Test is not empty then you will get a bunch of errors.
3. Also assumes that Performace_Test is on the same cluster as you specified in the `pg_dump` command.

Comment: This gives me an error: pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive.

Comment: Then either the `temp.bak` file was not created with the `pg_dump` command you gave or it is corrupted. Can you open the file to see if it is a plain text dump? Another thought occurred to me, there maybe an issue with the space in the directory name. Try copying/moving the file from "Database Backup" to a directory without a space in the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
     psql Performance_Test < test.bak
```

Comment: That won't work as the dump file is in custom format and will need `pg_restore`.